# Method get called for showing the Left Master ViewController in UISplitviewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ios5.1

I have recently created a sample Master Detail UISplitViewController project in XCode 4.3.2 (iOS 5.1).

Now once i select the barbuttonitem in deail view the root view is displayed .So i want to know which method get called when i select the bar button item.

Following code used for doing this :

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{

     barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Left", @"Left");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];

}
```

The aim behind is to know the method name so that i can set a custom Button with image and set it in navigation bar and call that particular method for showing root master view.

Answer (score 0):

I **think** the method you're looking for is:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)button;
```

Comment: Or maybe -(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController